Win32com failing to quit and save
I am using openpyxl in order to populate an excel sheet, but because it would contain formulas, I am trying to use win32com in order to refresh the sheet in order to get the calculated values from it.
The code I have to do this is this function
def refresh_book(book_path, filename):
    CoInitialize()
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = False
    xl.Interactive = False
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    xl.EnableEvents = False

    book = xl.Workbooks.Open(path.abspath(book_path + filename))

    book.RefreshAll()

    time.sleep(5)
    
    book.Save()

    xl.Quit()
    xl = None
    del book, xl
    time.sleep(5)
    CoUninitialize()

The book needs to refresh up to 6 times in one run of the program. When I run the program, the first time the file gets refreshed, it works, but the second time it always prompts me to save to a different location due to this error: Your changes could not be saved to '{filename}' because of a sharing violation. Try saving to a different file. I tried opening the excel file myself when the SaveAs prompt came up and I was locked out of that too.
I have also tried using SaveAs to output to a temporary file, delete the original file, then rename the temporary file 'called temp.xlsx', but I got a different error that '{autogenerated filename} could not be found'
What could be the issue? Am I forced to force any open excel instance anytime I want to do this?

Also in addition to all of this, when the book.Save() method is called, it creates an autogenerated named file with no extension. How do I not make it do that?
